# Postgres create table as from multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, create-table

I have a datamining problem with a very large number of attributes (>15,000). I represent the data in multiple tables with a common Id field. Having deleted empty attributes, I want to merge the resulting smaller tables so I can calculate correlations to remove redundent attributes.
I can join the tables easily with:

```
select * from lrg_bin0 k0
  join lrg_bin1 k1 on k0.id = k1.id
  join lrg_bin2 k2 on k0.id = k2.id
  join lrg_bin3 k3 on k0.id = k3.id
```

but when I try to create a new table with:

```
Create table mrg0 as (
  select * from lrg_bin0 k0
    join lrg_bin1 k1 on k0.id = k1.id
    join lrg_bin2 k2 on k0.id = k2.id
    join lrg_bin3 k3 on k0.id = k3.id
)
```

Postgress complains with 'column "id" specified more than once'

The very large number of attributes means I am doing everything programatically so answers suggesting queries I can generate would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `using` in instead of `on`

```
create table mrg0 as 
select *
from
    lrg_bin0 k0
    join lrg_bin1 k1 using (id)
    join lrg_bin2 k2 using (id)
    join lrg_bin3 k3 using (id)
```

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

> Also, USING implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns will be included in the join output, not both

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in SQL when you perform a join using on, the matching column will be included once per table it's found in. What you can do is specify which table you want the column from ala:

```
Create table mrg0 as (
  select k1.id, ... from lrg_bin0 k0
    join lrg_bin1 k1 on k0.id = k1.id
    join lrg_bin2 k2 on k0.id = k2.id
    join lrg_bin3 k3 on k0.id = k3.id
)
```

Comment: I like your solution because it's explicit vs USING which is implied.

Comment: This approach requires that each column is specified individually which is not practical in this context.

Comment: I "personally" don't like to see * in my code that's all. With this approach I would have to name out my columns explicitly and alias them in order to keep them from clashing or not include the duplicate id column.  When I read the code I would know exactly which columns are being pulled into my target table.

Comment: @PaulSmith how isn't this practical?  Because you have to name out the id you want from the table you want?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Per docs and your answer "Also, USING implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns will be included in the join output, not both."  Keyword being implies. I don't like to imply if I can be explicit nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @Bob, as I mentioned in the original question, I have thousands of columns, so replacing the '...' in astine's suggestion with individually named columns instead of '*' is not a practical option. Of course it is possible to do, but not what I was looking for. Also I do not think you are quite correct in your understanding of 'USING'. In this context it means that it is the same column in the tables being joined and not two seperate columns which happen to share a name.